# How to Stop Automatic Scrolling of Image Slider on Touch Event

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, imageview

I have created an automatic image slider using custom `ViewPager` Now i want to know how to stop the automatic sliding of images on touch and start the slider again from it was left when touch is released.

Here is my CustomViewPager.java :-

```
public class CustomViewPager extends ViewPager {

    private boolean isPagingEnabled = true;

    public CustomViewPager(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        return this.isPagingEnabled && super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        return this.isPagingEnabled && super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
    }

    public void setPagingEnabled(boolean b) {
        this.isPagingEnabled = b;
    }


}
```

Here is ImageAdapter.java :-

```
public  class SlidingImage_Adapter extends PagerAdapter {


    Context context;
    int images[];
    LayoutInflater inflater;


    public SlidingImage_Adapter(Context context, int images[]) {

        this.context = context;
        this.images = images;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }



    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((View) object);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return images.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int position) {
        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sliding_images, container, false);


        final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) itemView
                .findViewById(R.id.image);


        imageView.setImageResource(images[position]);

        container.addView(itemView, 0);

        return itemView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view.equals(object);
    }

    @Override
    public void restoreState(Parcelable state, ClassLoader loader) {
    }

    @Override
    public Parcelable saveState() {
        return null;
    }

}
```

Here is Fragment.java where i am using this CustomViewPager :-

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";
    TextView tv_slider, tv_button;
    RelativeLayout dummyView;
    CustomViewPager mViewPager;

    Timer timer;
    final long DELAY_MS = 1000;//delay in milliseconds before task is to be executed
    final long PERIOD_MS = 3000;



    private static int currentPage = 0;
    private static int NUM_PAGES = 0;
     int images[] = {R.drawable.ecommerce, R.drawable.digital_marketing, R.drawable.explainer, R.drawable.it_services,
            R.drawable.mobile_app, R.drawable.seo, R.drawable.software, R.drawable.webdesign};
    SlidingImage_Adapter imageAdapter;


    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public HomeFragment() {

    }

    public static HomeFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        HomeFragment fragment = new HomeFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);


        }
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
         View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

         tv_slider=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tv_slider);
         tv_slider.setTypeface(EasyFonts.robotoLight(this.getActivity()));
         tv_button=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tv_button);
         tv_button.setTypeface(EasyFonts.robotoLight(this.getActivity()));


        mViewPager = (CustomViewPager) v.findViewById(R.id.pager);
        imageAdapter = new SlidingImage_Adapter(getActivity(),images);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(imageAdapter);




        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        final Runnable Update = new Runnable() {
           public void run() {
                if (currentPage == NUM_PAGES) {
                    currentPage = 0;
                }
                mViewPager.setCurrentItem(currentPage++, true);

            }
        };

                Timer swipeTimer = new Timer();
       swipeTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
           public void run() {
               handler.post(Update);
           }
       }, DELAY_MS, PERIOD_MS);






        CirclePageIndicator indicator = (CirclePageIndicator)
                v.findViewById(R.id.indicator);

        indicator.setViewPager(mViewPager);

        final float density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;

         //Set circle indicator radius
        indicator.setRadius(3 * density);

        NUM_PAGES =images.length;



        // Pager listener over indicator
        indicator.setOnPageChangeListener(new CustomViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                currentPage = position;

            }



            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int pos, float arg1, int arg2) {

                switch (pos){

                    case 0:
                        tv_slider.setText(getString(R.string.es_content));
                        break;

                    case 1:
                        tv_slider.setText(getString(R.string.dm_content));
                        break;

                    case 2:
                        tv_slider.setText(getString(R.string.ev_content));
                        break;

                    case 3:
                        tv_slider.setText(getString(R.string.it_content));
                        break;

                    case 4:
                        tv_slider.setText(getString(R.string.md_content));
                        break;

                    case 5:
                        tv_slider.setText(getString(R.string.seo_content));
                        break;

                    case 6:
                        tv_slider.setText(getString(R.string.sd_content));
                        break;

                    case 7:
                        tv_slider.setText(getString(R.string.wd_content));
                        break;

                }



            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int pos) {

            }
        });


        return v;


    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have found a third party library ["Library Link"](https://github.com/Trinea/android-auto-scroll-view-pager) and it has built-in methods for starting and stopping the automatic scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) documentation,  the onTouchEvent which you have already overridden is where to look at.

Now instead of calling super.onTouchEvent(event) again as you did in your method. implement your own custom action. by calling super, you're accepting the default behavior.

Answer (score 0):

this is my example code it's working good =>

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    final long DELAY_MS = 1000;//delay in milliseconds before task is to be executed
    final long PERIOD_MS = 3000;
    int currentPage = 0;
    public Timer timer;
    public Timer swipeTimer;
    public static boolean startSlider = true;
    public TextView textView;
    public LinearLayout layout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);

        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        final Runnable Update = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                if (currentPage == 6) {
                    currentPage = 0;
                }
                currentPage++;
                textView.setText(String.valueOf(currentPage));

            }
        };


        swipeTimer = new Timer();
        swipeTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (startSlider){
                    handler.post(Update);
                }

            }
        }, DELAY_MS, PERIOD_MS);

        layout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (startSlider){
                    startSlider = false;
                }else {
                    startSlider = true;
                }
            }
        });

    }

}
```

Comment: its getting stopped but slider is not restarting after it

Comment: Update my answer please check it

Comment: no bro its not working now its not even getting stop on touch event\